# Loading foreign values in Svelte doesn't work

Tags: svelte

I'm working on Svelte at the moment. I have a page where I load some contacts. Those contacts have a field "company_id", which corresponds to the "id" field of a company.
I then tried to replace this "company_id" with the company.name value. I tried many many solutions, but it did never work. I always got "undefined" or "{ Object Promise }" in the  which was bound to the value. But when I did output the value to the console, it worked. But in the  not. I think this might be, because the value doesn't get rerenderet on the page. If I put the code to load the company name in a function and did bind it to a button, it worked in the  as well.

How can I solve this problem?

Here you can find the code for the index.svelte:

```
<script>
  import EntityTable from "../_Reusable/EntityTable.svelte";

  let columns = [
    {"column": "firstname", "type": "text", "name": "Vorname"},
    {"column": "lastname", "type": "text", "name": "Nachname"},
    {"column": "company_id", "type": "foreignEntity", "name": "Firma"},
    {"column": "language", "type": "text", "name": "Sprache"}
  ];

</script>

<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-9">
    <h2>Kontakte</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <a role="button" href="#/contacts/create" class="btn btn-secondary">
      Kontakt erstellen
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<EntityTable entityType="contacts" columns={columns}></EntityTable>
```

EntityTable.svelte:

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  import pluralize from "pluralize";
  

  export let entityType;
    export let columns;
  
  let data = [];
  let foreignEntities = {};
  
  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/" + entityType)
  .then(async function (response) {
    data = response.data;
    await columns.forEach(async column => {
      if (column.type == "foreignEntity") {
        let foreignEntityName = pluralize.plural(column.column.replace("_id", ""))
        await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/" + foreignEntityName)
          .then(function(response) {
            foreignEntities[foreignEntityName] = response.data;
          });
        data.forEach(row => {
          row[column.column.replace("_id", "")] = foreignEntities[foreignEntityName].find(x => x._id === row[column.column]).name;
        });
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  function deleteEntity(id) {
    axios.delete("http://localhost:3001/api/" + entityType + "/" + id)
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      if (response.status == 200) {
        data = data.filter(item => {
          return item._id != id
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  async function testing() {
    data.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
    });
  }

  async function load() {
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      console.log(row);
      columns.forEach(function(column) {
        if (column.type == "foreignKey") {
          try {
            let response = axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/" + "companies" + "/" + row[column.column]);
            console.log(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
</script>

<button on:click={testing}>Test</button>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        {#each columns as column}
          <th scope="col">{column.name}</th>
        {/each}
        <th scope="col">Aktionen</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {#each data as row,row_i}
      <tr>
        {#each columns as column}
          {#if column.type == "image"}
            <td><img src={row[column.column]} alt="" height="35px;"></td>
          {:else}
            <td>{row[column.column]}</td>
          {/if}
        {/each}
        <td>
          <a href="/#/{entityType}/{row._id}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-0">Ansehen</a>
          <a href="/#/{entityType}/{row._id}/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-0">Bearbeiten</a>
          <button on:click={deleteEntity(row._id)} class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-0">Löschen</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {/each}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `{ Object Promise }` means you did not `await`/`.then` your request properly.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. But before the return (which returns the value to the template), I also output the value using console.log() and there the value did get output correctly, altought the return statement came AFTER the console.log(). Have you an idea why that is?

Comment: No, and the relevant code does not seem to be included in the question.

Comment: That's because I have tried so any different codes (with and without async, in functions, bound to an element, and so on). Now I trashed everything again.

Comment: Your questions should give a minimal reproducible example, though. If you do not demonstrate the actual problem, solving it will be hard.

Comment: I did now updated the code so that it shows the problem. Now the column "company" does just show "undefined".

Comment: This is still far from minimal. It cannot just be run because of all the API dependencies. A really minimal example would be something with dummy data that can run in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/). Have you stepped through your code with a debugger and checked what kinds of objects are returned and what kind of properties are actually accessed? All that data manipulation via replaced strings looks brittle.